# How can a tourist rent a house or apartment or any other residence in Germany except hotel?

Tags: germany, rental

I'm planning to travel to Germany for two months and  currently looking for a place where I will be staying. Firstly I was looking for a hotel, but it was quite expensive as I'll be staying there for two months. So I'm looking for a residence not hotel.

I heard that most Germany houses are monthly rent basis, but I don't know what should I bring or what the requirements are, like documents, visa, etc. I'm not looking for a big house or roomy apartment. It would be just a small area only for myself.

How can a tourist rent a house/apartment or any other residence in Germany?

Comment: did you try airbnb? it should be cheaper than a hotel.

Comment: It's totally inconceivable you could "normally rent!" a house in Germany; the paperwork is astounding and it would certainly be a year or more minimum.  What you want is just an ordinary holiday rental (a "gite"), which you rent by the week - usually saturday to saturday in germany.  There are a huge, huge number for rent. Which city will you be in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be looking for accommodation that is explicitly listed for short stays.

The majority of "regular" German flats-for-rent come unfurnished and you will have a hard time convincing the landlord to rent it to you when there are other people interested in lending it for >=12 months. That is especially true if you do not have a residence permit. Also, rules such as that the walls need to be freshly painted when moving out are by no means uncommon.

Consider looking for places that are listed as vacation rentals. Your favorite search engine should find you some sites to search for them. AirBnB may also be an option (despite the fact that the legal situation for people *offering* accommodation within Germany on AirBnB is a bit tricky).

Comment: For 2 months, it is definitely vacation rentals. If you are in a bigger town or a touristy area, the Tourism office (Fremdenverkehrsamt) may have lists of vacation apartments; contact them and let them know about your requirements. If you are going to a university town, and your two months are within the university vacations, you may also find rooms normally rented to students.

Comment: @MaxWyss - Thanks for the addition. For the "find rooms normally rented to students", http://www.wg-gesucht.de is one of the standard sites (but it is in German). There are also often some temporary offers outside of the lecture-free time (for example, when people go on an internship).

Comment: I find it a bit surprising people are recommending "airbnb". The overwhelming leader is holiday-rentals, and then vrbo.  We rent gites all over europe 10 or more times per year, and I've never found anything on "airbnb", it's just a new startup.  it would be like mentioning "bing" or something versus google

Comment: There are 34,400 weekly holiday rentals (gites) for rent in Germany - !!  Holiday rentals, which is by far the biggest in the business (the google of that business), has already bought-up all the smaller holiday rentals sites in Germany. Simply click homeaway.de.  it just couldn't be easier.  (As I say, simply use homeaway.co.uk .. since it's in English  it's the same database, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't be easier, just click here

http://www.holiday-rentals.co.uk

or here

http://www.vrbo.com

There are literally 10s of thousands waiting for you

Holiday rentals (you rent one week at a time) are huge in Europe ("gites", yo'd say in France for example)

I wouldn't bother with airBnB - that's just a trendy start-up, focussed on one-night-at-a-time things

There are 10s of thousands of well established holiday-rental properties on holiday-rentals.co.uk -- you'll have a vast range of choices.

Note that I say ".co.uk" just since it's in English - they have sites in every language. it's a huge company.

You mention it's only you, so I clicked "sleeps 2" and immediately found 4000 options..again you don't mention what part of germany (it's a big place!)

[image]

You can easily pay as little as 20 or 30 euros a night...(noticed I selected "low to high price")

[image]